How to make Vuforia with aab and split binary work?
I'm experiencing a persistent issue where the Vuforia database is not recognized when I build my app as an Android App Bundle (AAB) with split binary options. However, when I build the project as an APK, everything functions correctly.
Here's what I've explored so far:
I understand that there are specific considerations with the StreamingAssets folder in AAB, such as potential delays in downloading contents.
I attempted to package the Vuforia database using AssetBundles. Unfortunately, it seems that the .dat file cannot be included in an AssetBundle. For reference, the app does upload and I can open it. It is just Vuforia which doesnt work!
I have a loading scene in Unity and my main Scene which gets loaded after
Setup Details:
Unity 2022.3.25f1
Vuforia 10.22.5
Build App Bundle (Google Play) [Check]
Split Application Binary [Check]

Base Scene Size: ~50MB
Main Scene Size: ~1.5GB

I've spent numerous hours over several nights trying to resolve this without success. Does anyone have suggestions on how to ensure the Vuforia database is properly recognized and loaded in an AAB format? Any insights or fixes would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
MotionBrain
I tried this to delay the streaming asset folder.
    IEnumerator Start()
    {

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        yield return null;
#else
            string[] assetPackNames = AndroidAssetPacks.GetCoreUnityAssetPackNames();
            if (!AndroidAssetPacks.coreUnityAssetPacksDownloaded)
            {
                yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForAssetPacksDownload(assetPackNames));
            }
            else{
                yield return StartCoroutine(CheckAssetPacksDownloaded(assetPackNames));
            }
#endif

    }

    IEnumerator WaitForAssetPacksDownload(string[] assetPackNames)
    {
        bool allDownloaded = false;
        // App cannot load without UnityStreamingAssetsPack being downloaded first
        while (!allDownloaded)
        {
            var operation = AndroidAssetPacks.GetAssetPackStateAsync(assetPackNames);
            yield return operation; // Wait for the state check to complete
 
            if (operation.isDone)
            {
                allDownloaded = true;
            }
 
            if (!allDownloaded)
            {
                // Wait before checking again to avoid spamming checks
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
            }
        }
        errorTtext.SetText("All asset packs downloaded.");

        AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
        asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;

        while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            float progress = asyncOperation.progress * 100;
            loadingPercent.text = (int)progress + "%";

            if (asyncOperation.progress >= 0.90f)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
                asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
        
    }

EDIT:
Vuforia works if the size of the app is < 150MB.

Not sure if it helps but some information on how to reduce the app size is available here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/unity-extension/building-large-vuforia-engine-apps-unity

Thanks for the reply. The size is not the main issue here. I can upload it to the google play store. But the Vuforia Database does not get loaded. I won't be able to reduce the app size.

Found a Solution:
Reverted to Vuforia 9.8.5.
And used this code while loading my MainScene (the big scene)
private string datUrl = "url.dat";
private string xmlUrl = "url.xml";
private string datasetName = "datasetName";    
IEnumerator DownloadAndLoadDatasets()
    {
        // Download DAT file
        UnityWebRequest datRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(datUrl);
        yield return datRequest.SendWebRequest();
        if (datRequest.isNetworkError || datRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            statusText.text += "Failed to download DAT file: " + datRequest.error;
            yield break;
        }

        // Download XML file
        UnityWebRequest xmlRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(xmlUrl);
        yield return xmlRequest.SendWebRequest();
        if (xmlRequest.isNetworkError || xmlRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            statusText.text += "Failed to download XML file: " + xmlRequest.error;
            yield break;
        }

        // Save downloaded files
        string datPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, datasetName + ".dat");
        string xmlPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, datasetName + ".xml");
        File.WriteAllBytes(datPath, datRequest.downloadHandler.data);
        File.WriteAllBytes(xmlPath, xmlRequest.downloadHandler.data);

        // Load and activate dataset
        LoadAndActivateDataset(datPath, xmlPath);
    }

    void LoadAndActivateDataset(string datPath, string xmlPath)
    {
        ObjectTracker objectTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
        DataSet dataSet = objectTracker?.CreateDataSet();
       
        if (dataSet != null /*&& dataSet.Load(xmlPath, VuforiaUnity.StorageType.STORAGE_ABSOLUTE)*/)
        {
            objectTracker.Stop();
            objectTracker.ActivateDataSet(dataSet);
            objectTracker.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            statusText.text += "Failed to load dataset.";
        }
    }

